# Is it possible to use transitions on glisten layers?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I created a custom layer, according to this material:
 http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.1.1/#_creating_a_layer, and added it to my application:

```
MobileApplication.getInstance().addLayerFactory(LAYER_NAME, () -> customLayer);
```

Now I would like to add a transition to  this layer. You can use transitions on `View` like:   `view.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInDownTransition:new)`

`Layer` doesn't provide a method like that. So I tried this  approach to apply a transition:

```
private void showLayer() {
    MobileApplication.getInstance().showLayer(LAYER_NAME);
    new BounceInDownTransition(customLayer).play();
}
```

When I call `showLayer()` for the first time the transition appears to be incomplete. The first part, where the layer should get transitioned out of view, is missing. Each further invocation of `showLayer()` shows the complete transition.

Are layers meant to be used in conjuction with transitions at all? 
If possible what is the recommended way?

Comment: The [release](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-mobile-2-2-0-released/) of the new Charm 2.2.0 version already includes layer transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in transitions in Gluon Charm, since all you need is pass a node to them, and call play to start the animation.

In case of the Gluon's Layers, there's no built-in mechanism as for Views, but you can easily add it to your class.

This will create a bounce-in effect for showing and bounce-out effect for hiding.

```
public class MyLayer extends Layer {

    private final Node root;
    private final double size = 150;

    public MyLayer() {
        final BounceInDownTransition transitionIn = new BounceInDownTransition(this, true);
        final BounceOutDownTransition transitionOut = new BounceOutDownTransition(this, true);
        transitionOut.setOnFinished(e -> hide());

        Button button = new Button("", MaterialDesignIcon.CLOSE.graphic());
        button.setOnAction(e -> transitionOut.playFromStart());
        root = new StackPane(button);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        getChildren().add(root);

        getGlassPane().getLayers().add(this);

        showingProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            if (nv) {
                layoutChildren();
                setOpacity(0);
                transitionIn.playFromStart();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        getGlassPane().setBackgroundFade(GlassPane.DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_FADE_LEVEL);
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        getGlassPane().setBackgroundFade(0.0);
        super.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void layoutChildren() {
        root.setVisible(isShowing());
        if (!isShowing()) {
            return;
        }
        root.resize(size, size);
        resizeRelocate((getGlassPane().getWidth() - size)/2, (getGlassPane().getHeight()- size)/2, size, size);
    }
}
```

And now, add the layer:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    addViewFactory(BASIC_VIEW, () -> new BasicView(BASIC_VIEW));

    addLayerFactory("My Layer", () -> new MyLayer());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it too. I've edited my answer with a fix: call `layoutChildren()` before starting the animation. Anyway, I'l create an internal issue for this.

Comment: This issue should be fixed with the [release](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-mobile-2-2-0-released/) of the new Charm 2.2.0 version. Can you check?